# Issue : ListBox hides all the stack panel and text boxes with in them, Wpf

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

I want to bind my textboxes in wpf xaml. That is doing perfectly but when i get textbox with his x:Name="myTextbox" in codebehind. He says

"The name 'myTextbox' does not exist in the current context"

Answer (score 0):

Using *WPF*, you cannot access items by name if there are inside a *DataTemplate*, like in your case, probably. However is not a good practice to modify the template using code behind. If you want to use correctly *WPF*, take a look at *MVVM* pattern.

In your case, the *ListBox* should be bound to an **ObservableCollection** and inside the template you can bind your textbox or whatever you have to the **Item** object.

Answer (score 0):

Don't access the textbox like this : `x:Name="myTextbox"`
Instead access it like `myTextbox.Text = "Hello World";`.